# Oracle database - connection request timed out - after client windows joins a domain on server 2012

Tags: oracle, networking, dns, virtualbox

I have a total of 3 systems, all installed on the Oracle Virtual box.

A: Windows 7 64 bit - Oracle database 11g R2 installed
B: Windows 7 64 bit - Used for testing developed application
C: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition - as a domain controller

Initially, I had only two systems, A and B, and the application on system B was able to connect to oracle database on system A.

After I installed system C on another Virtual Machine in VirtualBox and created it as a domain controller, and had the systems A and B join the new domain created, I am not able to connect to the oracle database on system A.

The error I was getting was: `Connection request timed out` - I checked on system A and database was stopped. I tried login using `sqlplus` and it failed with the 'No listener running', and I used the `lsnrctl start` to start the listener.

Then, I was able to connect using `sqlplus` on system A.

But, still the application on system B can't connect to database and receives - `Connection time out`.

I have checked the accessibility issues, system A is visible and accessible from system B and I get a proper ping request reply entries.

Can some one help me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. The problem was that, on system A, the firewall had to be turned off separately for the domain. It was already off for the `Public Network` and `Home Network`, but it had be turned off third time again for the `Domain Network`.